# Blazor ошибка JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

На Blazor Server (.net5) хочу импортировать модуль js и вызвать функцию, но получаю ошибку, что делаю не так?

[image: Путь до файла js]

выше путь до файла js

это на странице razor:

```
@code{

    private IJSObjectReference module;
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
                "import", "./script/MyScript.js");
        }
    }

    private async Task Click()
    {
        await module.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
            "showAlert");
    }
}
```

и сам js

```
 function showAlert() {
        alert("test message");
    }
```

ошибка:

```
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: "Could not find 'showAlert' ('showAlert' was undefined).
Error: Could not find 'showAlert' ('showAlert' was undefined).
    at http://localhost:41916/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:67714
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at e.findFunction (http://localhost:41916/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:67674)
    at v (http://localhost:41916/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:69416)
    at http://localhost:41916/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:70362
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at e.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (http://localhost:41916/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:70335)
    at http://localhost:41916/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:26442
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at e.invokeClientMethod (http://localhost:41916/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:26412)"
```

Comment: я вообще не в теме, но может быть надо `function showAlert()` => `export function showAlert()` ?

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо это помогло. интересно почему этого нет во всех тех примерах что я гуглил =)

Comment: не там гуглили просто, примеры есть в [документации](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0), которая находится по запросу [`JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>`](https://www.google.com/search?q=JS.InvokeAsync%3CIJSObjectReference%3E) в гугле